# How to integrate Stripe STPPaymentOptionsViewController with Swift 5?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, swift5, xcode12

Previously I integrated STPAddCardViewController in Swift, where user can give the card details and I sending the token to backend. Now I have to integrate the STPAddCardViewController with swift5. I checked Stripe docs -https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic.
Unable to setup the ephemeral key and also proceed with some construct thing. I have inherited
STPPaymentOptionsViewControllerDelegate and the delegate method

func paymentOptionsViewController(_ paymentOptionsViewController: STPPaymentOptionsViewController, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error) {

```
}

func paymentOptionsViewControllerDidFinish(_ paymentOptionsViewController: STPPaymentOptionsViewController) {
   
}

func paymentOptionsViewControllerDidCancel(_ paymentOptionsViewController: STPPaymentOptionsViewController) {
    
}
But I am unable to send the token to backend.When we used card the token used to be like this start like this -> "tok_ ..." Now if used Payment then token will start with "P.."
```

I will be highly obliged if any body help me regarding this.

Comment: Can you clarify? You say you're "unable" to do a couple of things but not what you tried, what you expected and what error you got instead. "token will start with "P.."" — yes because Tokens are deprecated and the component would create PaymentMethods `pm_xxx` instead — you use these with a PaymentIntent client_secret obtained from your backend server , to complete a payment on the frontend. It's covered in the doc you linked. https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic#submit-payment

Comment: @karllekko Thanks for answering. Actually I didn't understood the how to set the ephemeral key. Previously I am navigating the user to STPAddCardViewController and getting the data in the delegate methods. But now  I am not able to how to implement the process to get the token . Can you please guide me regarding this.,